# Nyx doesn't prompt for password

Tags: nyx

I have tor and nyx on the same server. In the torrc file, I enabled the ControlPort (at 9051) and I pasted the hashed password to access the port.

When I launch nyx (from root or another user) I don't get a password prompt and after a while, nyx stops with this error: `Unable to authenticate: socket connection failed ([Errno 111] Connection refused)`

After launching nyx with the `-d` option, I have this error (both with a config file containing the password or without needing my input): `Error while receiving a control message (SocketClosed): received exception "[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer"`

Do you know how to resolve this issue?